# Is there a specific word for the process where someone is trying to learn a specific piece of information from you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a specific word for the process where someone is trying to learn a specific piece of information in a conversation with you without revealing what he wants ?

Comment: An example might be useful.

Comment: I've claimed that 'Is there a term for a masked / veiled question to find sensitive information?' seems very much like a duplicate of 'Is there a specific word for the process where someone is trying to learn a specific piece of information in a conversation with you without revealing what he wants?' (accepted answer 'fishing expedition') but that CV-suggestion seems to have been removed without explanation. Not what I want on a reputable site.

Comment: The word is "Stack Exchange".

Comment: Are you pumping us for information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a term for a masked / veiled question to find sensitive information?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/454158/is-there-a-term-for-a-masked-veiled-question-to-find-sensitive-information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [fishing expedition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fishing_expedition) (or, in a small way, merely *fishing*):

> A search or investigation undertaken with the hope, though not the stated purpose, of discovering information.
>
> —  Lexico by Oxford

It's also used in another, related context, of getting someone to offer you something you want. For example, if you mention that you're driving somewhere, someone else might *fish* for a lift.

Comment: Or, synonymously, *angling* for the info.

Comment: A fishing expedition is when you *don't* know quite what you are looking for, but will know it when you here it. It is a baseless inquiry.

Comment: In fact just ‘fishing’ can be enough.